# Grails create domain object in a different data source

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I want to create a domain object in different data sources based on a condition but when we instantiate a new object like `new Foo().save()` there is no way to set which data source it will be done.

I've also noticed that if I do `new Foo().dataSource2.save()` it still saves in default (unnamed) data source in addition to `dataSource2`. How can we instantiate object only in one data source and save only in there?

I'm using `grails 2.4.3`.

Edit: To make it clear. I want to dynamically pick which data source to create the user in during runtime.

Comment: Grails does not provide an out of box solution to this, however since it's built on Spring you should be able to make it work using an AbstractRoutingDataSource and some Thread local variables. You might lose secondary caching in Hibernate however, and there are likely going to be other quirks. It could be done, but it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `new Foo().dataSource2.save()` will not try to save it in the unnamed data source at a later point. This solution actually works.